# Return one value from a table using a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have this code:

```
public int GetUserIdByEmail(string email)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ZincModelContainer.CONNECTIONSTRING))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = String.Concat("SELECT [Zinc].[GetUserIdByEmail] (", email, ")");  //is this correct??? the problem lies here

      return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     } 
  }
}
```

I get the error here in above code. this is still not right 
I have my function now as below suggested by veljasije
thanks

Comment: if(dt.Rows.Count>0){userId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["UserId"]);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Zinc].[GetUserIdByEmail]
 (
   @Email varchar (100)
 )

 AS
 BEGIN

   SELECT zu.UserId from Zinc.Users zu WHERE Email = @Email

 END
```

And in you code change type of parameter from `NVarChar` to `VarChar`

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Zinc].[GetUserIdByEmail]
 (
   @Email varchar(100)
 )
 RETURNS int
 AS
 BEGIN

   DECLARE @UserId int;
   SET @UserId = (SELECT zu.UserId from Zinc.Users zu WHERE Email = @Email)

   RETURN @UserId                
 END
```

Comment: should i have a stored procedure or a function? I just want to return ONE value from the users table ie: the userId using the email address

Comment: If we talking about user defined function in database system, you can freely use a user function, both do the same, because here is speak about just SELECT. But, if you need to modify some data in database, then you must use stored procedure, because it is not allowed to change data through user defined functions.

Comment: ooo ok yes i just want to return a value but with my code as i have it now i get an error:  The multi-part identifier "alias.field" could not be bound??

Comment: Yes, you can use the both, only if you execute select from database. For data modification, you need to use stored procedure. Place it as answer if you think it was really help you.

Comment: thanks very much but i still have a problem with my code i have in my OP :) i get that error The multi-part identifier "alias.field" could not be bound??

Comment: Maybe you can try this: `String.Concat("SELECT [Zinc].[GetUserIdByEmail] ('", email, "')");` or even double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, specify the size for the @Email parameter in the sproc - without it, it will default to 1 character which will therefore not be attempting to match on the value you are expecting it to.

Always specify the size explicitly to avoid any issues (e.g. per Marc_s's comment, plus demo I blogged about [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/04/sql-cast-to-varchar-without-size.html), it behaves differently bu defaulting to 30 chars when using CAST/CONVERT )

Secondly, use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)
e.g.

```
userId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Even worse: the default length for a `varchar` parameter is **1 character**! The 30 char default applies to `CAST` and `CONVERT` ...

Comment: Thanks for the catch @marc_s! Quite right, corrected my answer.